# Can you install Visual Studio Emulator for Android on an EC2 instance?

Tags: android, visual-studio, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

I am wondering if it's possible to install the Visual Studio Emulator for Android on an EC2 instance.

I ask because I have done this, and presently that EC2 instance won't startup and is possibly lost forever.

The EC2 instance was running Windows Server 2003(or 2008?) and did report that it supports virtualization when looking at Task Manager.
I didn't do anything to enable Hyper-V, just installed it normally via the "next-next-finish" routine.

Anyone have luck putting this emulator on EC2?